# Uploading CSV files to Fusion Tables through Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, file-upload, stream, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to grab data from looker and insert it directly into Google Fusion Tables using the MediaFileUpload so as to not download any files and upload from memory. My current code below returns a TypeError. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Error returned to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvpython.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "csvpython.py", line 88, in main
    media = MediaFileUpload(dataq, mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 548, in __init__
    fd = open(self._filename, 'rb')
  TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Code in question:

```
for x, y, z in zip(look, destination, fusion):    

    look_data = lc.run_look(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(look_data)
    stream = io.StringIO()
    dataq = df.to_csv(path_or_buf=stream, sep=";", index=False)
    media = MediaFileUpload(dataq, mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)
    replace = ftserv.table().replaceRows(tableId=z, media_body=media, startLine=None, isStrict=False, encoding='UTF-8', media_mime_type='application/octet-stream', delimiter=';', endLine=None).execute()
```

After switching dataq to stream in MediaFileUpload, I have had the following returned to me:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "quicktestbackup.py", line 96, in <module>
     main()
   File "quicktestbackup.py", line 88, in main
     media = MediaFileUpload(stream, mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 548, in __init__
     fd = open(self._filename, 'rb')
   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.StringIO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataFrame.to_csv` is a void method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv%20Df) and any side effects from calling it are passed to `stream` and not `dataq`. That is, `dataq` is `NoneType` and has no data - your CSV data is in `stream`.
When you construct the media file from the io object, you need to feed it the data from the stream (and not the stream itself), thus its `getvalue()` [method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO.getvalue) is needed.

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=stream, ...)
media = MediaFileUpload(stream.getvalue(), ...)
```

The call to FusionTables looks to be perfectly valid.

Comment: Sorry I havent added the other lines in the error. I have edited the post with the Traceback errors

Comment: Based on your traceback, my assumption above is correct: your error is not with FusionTables, but with your construction of the media upload object.

Change `dataq` to `stream` as I suggest and the error will be resolved (or at minimum, be different). You'd also want to drop the creation of `dataq` as the CSV method does not return a valid object.

Comment: I have changed from dataq to stream and edited in the traceback in the post.

Comment: I had thought perhaps MediaFileUpload was `io` aware, but it is not. You'll have to pass the stream contents instead then. I've updated my answer to reflect the new information you've provided.

Comment: @tehhowch I have a task regarding fusion table. I may outsource the task if you can do it. Share your skype id if you are interested. thanks!